# How to pass an array of strings through an update view function for my tableview cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swift file currently using as a singleton which will eventually
be the location that I use to grab all the API data, I have a view file for my iboulets and a function to update the views for the tableview cells, along with a model file that has my variables and initializer. Everything works fine until I tried to pass through an array instead of a string, can you assist me in passing an array or arrays through my update views function.[`Current error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBcJA.png)

> Singleton

```
class DataServices{
    static let instance = DataServices()



    private let ackee = [

        RecipeInfo(image: "15", title: "Ackee & Saltfish", time: "30 mins", complication: "Easy", serving: "5 people", ingredients: ["Canned Ackee", "Black Pepper", "Salt Fish"], instructions: "again")
    ]



    func getRecipe() -> [RecipeInfo]{
        return ackee
    }
```

> Update View function for the cell

```
class RecipeCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ingredients: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var instructions: UILabel!




    func updateViews(recipe: RecipeInfo){
        recipeImage.image = UIImage(named: recipe.image)
        recipeTitle.text = recipe.title
        recipeTime.text = recipe.time
        recipeStatus.text = recipe.complication
        mealCount.text = recipe.serving
        ingredients.text = recipe.ingredients
        instructions.text = recipe.instructions

    }
```

> Model with variables and initializer

```
struct RecipeInfo {


    private(set) public var image: String
    private(set) public var title: String
    private(set) public var time: String
    private(set) public var complication: String
    private(set) public var serving: String
    private(set) public var ingredients: String
    private(set) public var instructions: String



    init(image: String, title: String, time: String, complication: String, serving: String, ingredients: String, instructions: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
        self.time = time
        self.complication = complication
        self.serving = serving
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.instructions = instructions
    }
```

Comment: Replace `ingredients: String` with `ingredients: [String]` instead. For single ingredient (only a String, just do `RecipeInfo(image... ingredients: [myIngredient],...)` For the updateView, it depends how you want to show multiple ingredients, only first? `ingredients.text = recipe.ingredients.first` or `ingredients.text = recipe.ingredients.joined(separator: ", ")`, etc.

Comment: You're awesome, that solved my issue big time. However the array isn't displaying the list as I wish it would. I am trying to have the ingredients in separate cells

Comment: FYI - There is no need for the `init` method in your `RecipeInfo` struct. You get that exact `init` for free. And change all of the properties to be `let`. No need for `var` or the `private (set) public`.

Comment: I was only doing it the way I was taught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear : `ingredients` is declared as `String` but in the Singleton an array (`[String]`) is passed. The name implies an array yet.

And the `private(set)` variables might look pretty cool but they are nonsense. This is not Objective-C. If you want constants declare them as constants (`let`)

This is sufficient, you get the initializer for free:

```
struct RecipeInfo {       
    let image: String
    let title: String
    let time: String
    let complication: String
    let serving: String
    let ingredients: [String]
    let instructions: String
}
```

To display `ingredients` in the table view join the array

```
ingredients.text = recipe.ingredients.joined(separator: ", ")
```